# The Traveller's Lament

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> I could visit the darkness,
>   if the sky would but let me,
>   But I venture as far,
>   as explosions will get me
>
> I leave markings behind me,
>   when I breathe out just right,
>   but I don't really care,
>   if it's morning or night.
>
> I rely on the touch,
>   of a woman or man
>   To give up my thoughts,
>   in the air, or on land.
>
> If none of the people
>   I need can be found,
>   My record of deeds,
>   may be found on the ground.

Who am I, and how do you know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it ...

> ... an Airplane?

I could visit the darkness,
if the sky would but let me,

> An Airplane could go to space, if air density allowed it.

But I venture as far,
as explosions will get me

> Turbine fire could be seen as a set of continuous explosions

I leave markings behind me,
when I breathe out just right,

> Condensate stripes

but I don't really care,
if it's morning or night.

> Can fly any time of day

I rely on the touch,
of a woman or man
To give up my thoughts,
in the air, or on land.

> Needs a pilot to steer and read and interpret instruments

If none of the people
I need can be found,

> Oh my god they're all dead!

My record of deeds,
may be found on the ground.

> Black Box after crash

Comment: Nice work!  The explosions referred to the combustion occurring, but I'll call that semantics =D.  Also, I like your interpretation of "give up my thoughts."  I had originally referred to disabling auto-pilot.

Comment: Thx :) ! Did you make this riddle yourself or did you find it somewhere?

Comment: `If none of the people I need can be found` part made me laugh out loud.

Comment: @AndreasT I'm trying to only add riddles that I've made up on here, honestly.  It makes the game far more interesting, to me.

Comment: @AycanYaşıt Yeah, I spent about 10 minutes deciding what I wanted that whole paragraph to say. =D -  And the response made me laugh, too =D